# How to save text fields values in core data in Mac (osx) application?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have created trivial application for osx which use core data(it is NOT document based application)

I have created an entity named myTable and I have 3 attributes inside (myString1,myString2 and myString3) which are all strings.

I have created 3 text fields and a save button in the .xib file. In the AppDelegate.h, i have created 3 IBOutlets for the text fields, and 1 IBAction for the save button.

In the AppDelegate.m, i have the following code so far:
(The default code has been omitted here for the sake of simplicity.)

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonHasBeenClicked:(id)sender {
//fill the array

NSArray * myArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[_firstTextField stringValue],[_secondTextField stringValue], [_thirdTextField stringValue], nil];

// how to save this array in coredata?


}
```

If I run the following code:

```
for (NSString *detail in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"Detail is: %@",detail);
}
```

I can verify that array has been populated with the values of the text fields. However, I am not sure should i save the values in array, and then insert them in coredata, or I should insert each text field value separately.

I know that I should do some key:value: coding here, but I have no idea where to start. Anyone can help me with this code, or post a link to some tutorial? I know how to save data with NSTableView and binding, but I can't find my way with text fields and coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case that someone else need solution for this, here it is:

```
    NSManagedObject *myObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"myTable" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [myObject setValue:[__firstTextField stringValue] forKey:@"myString1"];
    [myObject setValue:[_secondTextField stringValue] forKey:@"myString2"];
    [myObject setValue:[_thirdTextField stringValue] forKey:@"myString3"];
    //[self saveAction:myObject];
    // above solution works also, but the solution bellow is better
    NSError *myError = nil;
    if (![[self managedObjectContext]save:&myError]) {
        NSLog(@"Error while attempting to save the data");
    }
```

I didn't need the array after all, so I had remove that part.

Cheers